# Rails - No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, testing, rspec

Why does my test:

```
feature "Manage todos" do
  scenario "create a new todo" do
    visit root_path
    fill_in 'Email address', with: 'junk@snap2web.com'
    click_button 'Sign in'
    click_link('Add a new todo')
    fill_in 'Description', with: 'Buy some milk'
    click_button 'Create todo'
    expect(page).to have_css 'li.todo', text: 'Buy some Milk'
  end
end
```

error with:

```
1) Manage todos create a new todo
  Failure/Error: click_button 'Create todo'
  ActionController::RoutingError:
    No route matches [POST] "/todos/new"
```

When my routes has:

```
Todos::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'homepage'
  resource :session, only: [:create]
  resources :todos
end
```

and rake routes shows:

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
     root GET    /                         high_voltage/pages#show {:id=>"homepage"}
  session POST   /session(.:format)        sessions#create
    todos GET    /todos(.:format)          todos#index
          POST   /todos(.:format)          todos#create
 new_todo GET    /todos/new(.:format)      todos#new
edit_todo GET    /todos/:id/edit(.:format) todos#edit
     todo GET    /todos/:id(.:format)      todos#show
          PATCH  /todos/:id(.:format)      todos#update
          PUT    /todos/:id(.:format)      todos#update
          DELETE /todos/:id(.:format)      todos#destroy
     page GET    /pages/*id                high_voltage/pages#show
```

and my controller has:

```
$ cat app/controllers/todos_controller.rb 
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
  end

end
```

and the form has:

```
$ cat app/views/todos/new.html.erb 
Add a new todo
<%= form_for :todo do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create todo' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have exact same problem.  Form submission actually works If i click it myself.... Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-21 08:39:10 +1100
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML but rspec fails because click_button is hitting [POST] /contacts/new instead of [POST] /contacts we are missing something :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have

```
<%= form_for Todo.new do |f| %>
```

in your view

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your routes. As the test suggests, there is no route to POST to todos/new. You'll need to POST to todos/ and handle that in a create action in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

check that you haven't inadvertently added 2 form tags in your form.  I did this by copying a bootstrap snippet like this...

```
<div class="col-sm-8 contact-form">
  <form id="contact" method="post" class="form" role="form">
    <div class="row">
```

and wrapping it in a form_for tag...

```
<%= form_for @contact, url: contacts_path do |f| %>
```

The annoying thing was that it worked fine If I clicked the button manually but test failed

Answer (score 0):

Adding the path in the form field will redirect to the post path

```
<%= form_for :todo do, url: todos_path  |f| %>
```